# Vertx eventloop thread name

Tags: vert.x

I have multiple vert.x applications deployed. In some of the logs the thread name is displayed as "**ntloop-thread-1**" and in some cases it is displayed as "**vert.x-eventloop-thread-1**".

What is the difference between the two ?

Comment: Vert.x doesn't change the name of the thread. Probably related to the logging framework configuration

Comment: The logback.xml file is same across all applications. So it can't be logging framework issue. Can it be due to epoll or tcnative ?

Comment: Are you sure they're reporting the same thing? `ntloop-thread-1` is the name of threads Netty is using. Netty is used in Vert.x under the hood.

Comment: @alexeySoshin What could cause the vertx application to use netty loop name. I wrote a simple spring boot + vertx application which shows ntloop-thread-1 name. But I am not able to figure out how to get ntloop-thread-1 when I use the full blown application. Let me know if you would like to look at the sample application. I can put it on github.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that what happens is that SpringBoot intercepts some Vert.x internals, and not the other way around.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin But there us no such code in spring which will rename the vertx thread name.

Comment: I didn't explain myself correctly. Spring doesn't rename anything. There are always two thread pools - one for Netty, named `ntloop`, and another for Vert.x, named `vert.x-eventloop`. Usually only later of them is logged. But Spring probably finds the second thread pool through some reflection, and logs it too, although it shouldn't.